# highlight text in Div using JavaScript only(without using HTML)

Tags: javascript

I have a div like below

```
<div>01010101.11110000.11100010.10011001.00011111.00000001</div>
```

I want to highlight from 10th character to 15th character without using HTML tag in the DIV, as I need to highlight test based on the dynamic calculation and if I add any HTML tag inside the DIV it will increase the number of character inside the DIV. I am also not able to use the JavaScript SELECT and RANGE method as the text gets deselected when the user clicks anywhere on the screen.

Comment: Can you provide the full html?

Comment: What you want is not possible. To "highlight" some text, you need either an HTML element or an (programmatically created) user selection. The solution is to use a HTML element, just don't use HTML as data, store and manipulate the value in JS variable(s), and highlight the text according to the results you get with JS.

Comment: the above code is the HTML where I need to highlight the character

Comment: I have created a JavaScript code to select the text range but the issue with that is when user click anywhere in the screen the text get deselected.

Comment: Yes, that's why you've to create a HTML element for highlighiting.

Comment: @VivekKumarShukla I just reposted my answer, it may help you to move into some direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `textContent` property to get the characters from element. and if you will add any tags into div it will not change number of characters.

Also you can create element with already highlighted character with html and just place it over oiriginal element.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Teemu said in the comments, it's impossible to do this without wrapping it in some kind of HTML, so it would be best to handle the data in the Javascript and use the HTML only for displaying that data.

If you do it that way, then you could use the [Mark.js](https://markjs.io/) library, which is a JavaScript keyword highlighter. It was made for something like this and it has a bunch of neat features.